# Who are the people in the portraits in M's meeting room?

Tags: movie, league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen

At the beginning of "The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen" movie, Alan Quartermain is meeting with M. in a room.

As M. reveals, ""There have been other times when a danger upon the world required the services of singular individuals" - referring presumably to prior members of the League.

As they discuss and meet other team members, the camera pans around the room, and shows the portraits of different groups of people.

**Who are the people in the portraits?**

Presumably, they are the past League members, but I am unsure of who they are.

- One has a trio of a knight (with a cross on his tunic), a man with a crossbow and an eye mask; and someone else.
- One portrait contains 4 of what looks like Dumas' Three Musketeers, but it also has 2 random other dudes
- One has 4 people, one of whom seems to look like Oz' Scarecrow.

I will post screenshots below, if desired I have higher quality ones.

I'm OK with the answers that are based on any canon (e.g. movie/script; creative team interviews, or comics).

[image]

[image] [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer of questionable canon; I'd do it as a comment, but it's too long.

Per [IMDB's trivia section](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0311429/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv), the Screenplay lists the first one as :

- [Robin Hood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Hood) (the one in Green, center, I'm guessing)
- [Ivanhoe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivanhoe) (left)
- [Black Arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Arrow:_A_Tale_of_the_Two_Roses) (Robert Louis Stevenson; right)

The second painting shows:

- Porthos
- Athos
- Aramis
- D'Artagnan([The Three Muskateers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_musketeers) )
- [Sea Hawk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sea_Hawk)
- [Captain Blood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Blood_%28novel%29)

Nothing about the third, that I can find, although the 'Man in the Iron Mask' leaps to mind for one of 'em.

This being IMDB, there are no sources, sadly.

With luck, this will give someone else the ammo to find a canon source :)

UPDATE:

The third painting **may** be based on one in the comic:

- [The Reverend Dr. Syn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Syn)
- [Sir Percy & Marguerite Blakeney], the [Scarlet Pimpernel by Baroness Orczy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scarlet_Pimpernel)
- [Natty Bumppo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natty_Bumppo) (and other names), hero of [Last of the Mohicans by James Fenimore Cooper]
- [Lemuel Gulliver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemuel_Gulliver), of "Gulliver's Travels" by Jonathan Swift).
- [Fanny Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanny_Hill), of "Memoirs of a Woman of Pleasure or Fanny Hill" by John Cleland).

Comment: "The Black Arrow" is not a character in the Robert Louis Stevenson novel.

Answer (score 11):

This movie is plagued by production, development and correlation issues with the original comics. It is very difficult to compare and contrast the original source materials with what was shown in the movies. Using the IMDB I have referenced the characters as Hollywood's idea of a League of Extraordinary Gentlemen.

The [list of members](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_League_of_Extraordinary_Gentlemen_characters) of the League of Extraordinary Gentlemen from the comics is quite extensive and does not correspond to the images made for the movie. The first three are listed from the IMDB but none of the three are listed as members from the comic.

- Robin Hood - Movie, 1938 starring Errol Flynn
- Ivanhoe - Movie, 1952
- Black Arrow - Movie, 1948

The second picture appears to be the Three Musketeers (including D'Artagan) and two famed movie characters Sea Hawk and Captain Blood, None of these characters are listed on a comprehensive list of the LXG membership, so it is an oversight or a mistake that has not been corrected.

- Captain Blood - Movie, 1935
- The Sea Hawk - Movie, 1940

The list appears to be a Hollywood idea of the LXG since Captain Blood was a famous movie in the 1930s and Sea Hawk was famous in the 1940s both had Errol Flynn in starring roles.

The last image is from the League of 1780, called [Gulliver's Fellowship](http://lxg.wikia.com/wiki/Gulliver%27s_Fellowship) and is referenced from the comics.

This League as portrayed in the LXG movie appears to consist of [Dr. Syn](http://www.drsyn.com/), Sir Percy, Hawkeye and Gulliver. If Gulliver is the person in the bottom right corner he appears to be quite young. The ladies of the group are missing, which is a shame since judging from the Almanac they play a significant role in this league.

[image]